# Unfair employer

Tags: work-environment, employees

I have been working for this company for 13 months now. I have no qualification and I matriculated last year.

I thought this job would not only enable me to save money and broaden my knowledge. but some months down the line, the lady i used to work with quit her job because they did not want to increase her salary. all the work she did was now shifted to me along with my own work which was too much for me to handle but i did until February when my contract ended.

they then asked me to come back to the company as a Sales and Marketing Executive. i accepted but till this day they have not given me a contract to sign for the new position.

my problem is that they treat their employees like crap and they don't pay. they make you do more than 100 times more that what you are supposed to be doing, not only that but they also pile you up with too much and you are unable to finish it and they shout at you like a child at the end of the day.

right now i'm at a cross road because i don't know whether to continue working because i really need the money or to quit and have a piece of mind because right now I don't even look forward to going to work in the mornings.

I am still very young and I don't need this kid of stress in my life. Is it a good idea to quit? plus I have not signed a contract for this position I am in now

Comment: I'm confused as to the issue. Are you not getting paid currently? Or are you just not getting a contract? If you are not getting paid, do not return to the workplace.

Comment: My advice: Start looking for work before you quit. Book one day off each week if you need a day where you can go to attend interviews. If your manager declines you the days off you can be forceful about it, since you're planning on leaving anyways they will either fire you or give you the days off - either way, works for you.

Answer (score 4):

Curiosity overwhelms me ... How does one move from 'have no qualification' to 'Sales and Marketing Executive'?  And a better question is why did you agree to a position without having any paperwork such as a contract?

Sounds like a company that is trying to get as much out of their employees without having to pay or have any other employer obligations, perhaps by employing very young people that don't know any better.

I'd recommend getting a resume going and looking for other employment, as this situation does not seem permanent.

Comment: It's a pretty common move on shady business places. Quite a few companies put some pompous name on certain roles, like "Delta Level Sales Executive" instead of "Junion Salesman" to make the role seem more important when in truth is just the regular grunt work. On a certain financial institution on Brazil, you had 27 levels of _Administrative Managers_ - being a "Level 2 Administrative Manager", as my mother was, meant that you did basic admin work like typing correspondence or filing forms. But hey, she was a manager, wasn't she?

Comment: Ha.  Reminds me of the Cheers episode where the staff want raises and instead they get fancy titles.  <Woody Harrelson>  Senior Executive Bartender!!


That and anyone in a sales capacity the company doesn't want to look small, so indeed yes they balloon the titles.